# Modifying an existing Select statement in EF to include a new 0/1-Many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, one-to-many, datacontext

I've been handed a new program and told to maintain it. Admittedly I have not done that much with EF outside of tutorials.

The problem is as follows:  The program contains a select statement that feeds an export to Excel through a System.collections.generic.list.  At present there are no 0/1 to many relationships in it. (And no indication that the designers ever considered it.  No documentation).

I am confident that I have already set up the relevant models to provide that relationship but as yet I have not been able to figure out a way to modify the existing statement so that, for example, instead of one line with Key = f.id, there are now several, due to the child records.  It's been suggested to me that I try an .Include statement but in the current situation I have as yet been unable to find a way to make that work.  I'd rather not make radical changes at this early stage but I'm also considering tossing the entire thing out and starting over but I haven't had much progress with that either.

The overall current query structure is as follows (Field2 is what I'd like to do.):

```
  var result = new List<AnotherDataClass>();

  result= dataContext.ADataClass
     .Where(f => f.CreatedDate >= sDate && f.CreatedDate <= eDate)
     .Where(f => IdList.Contains(f.Id))
            .Select(f => new AnotherDataClass
           {

               Field1 = f.Id,
               Field2 = f.FromOneRecordOfManyField, 
               etc...
       }).ToList()...
```

Comment: Relationship (usually) includes two parties (tables), and the posted query contains just one. Which makes the whole post unclear what you're asking.

Comment: The provided code is not so sufficient enough to look up into this, but I am assuming `Field1` is the key and `Field2` is a List of another entity?

Comment: To LJ.  Yes.  My apologies.  I thought I was clear enough.  The current code only handles one table.  What I would like is for Field2 to be imported from another table.  In other words, the EF equivalent of a join, multiple rows of Field2 for a single value of Field1.